# Converting json file to another format

Tags: javascript, json

How best to convert the json file to another format? I read about the 'map 'method  but do not know how to use it.

```
[{"Southern":"9"},{"South-West":"83"},{"South-East":"448"},{"Western":"638"},{"North-Western":"706"},{"Eastern":"710"},{"North-East":"1055"}]
```

I would like to convert the:

```
        [
            ['Southern', 9],
            ['South-West', 83],                   
            ['South-East', 448],
            ['Western', 638],
            ['North-Western', 706],
            ['Eastern', 710],
            ['North-East', 1055],

        ]
```

Code:

```
 data.map(function(e) {
    ..........
    });
```

Comment: Are you sure you want an array of arrays? Would something like `{"Southern": 9, "South-West": 83}` not be more practical?

Answer (score 4):

```
newData = data.map(function(e) {
    var key = Object.keys(e)[0];
    return [ key, parseInt(e[key], 10) ];
});
```

However, it seems like it would be more useful if you converted it to a single object:

```
{ 
    'Southern': 9,
    'South-West': 83,
    'South-East': 448,
    'Western': 638,
    'North-Western': 706
    'Eastern': 710
    'North-East': 1055
}
```

This can be done with:

```
newObject = {};
data.forEach(function(e) {
    var key = Object.keys(e)[0];
    newObject[key] = e[key];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use map you can use a simple loop:

```
var result = [];
for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
  var key = Object.keys(arr[i])[0];
  var val = parseInt(arr[i][key], 10);
  result.push([key, val])
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/p4rrn3cf/1/)